# EIdReplyIMAP4Error in Indy

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, indy, indy10

What are possible causes to look into for an "EIdReplyIMAP4Error" exception?

This is in regards to connecting to an IMAP4 account using SSL/TLS. sslvSSLv23 for the SSLOptions.Method and utUseImplicitTLS for the UseTLS setting. the error was reported by an XP user, so I'm not sure if this might be a TLS version compatibility issue, or something completely unrelated. The documentation for Indy10 is a bit vague about what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `EIdReply...` exception means that the server returned a protocol-appropriate error reply in response to a command that your app sent to it.  In this case, your app sent an IMAP-related command, and the server replied with an IMAP-related error.  The properties of the `EIdReply...` exception contain the server's error details (error codes, string messages, etc).

Some `TIdIMAP` methods send single commands, but other methods send multiple commands internally, so to really know which exact command is failing, you need to log the actual commands/responses being exchanged.  Since SSL/TLS is involved, that usually rules out using an external sniffer, like WireShark.  However, Indy has its own logging capabilities.  You can attach one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components, such as `TIdLogFile or`TIdLogEvent, to the `TIdIMAP.Intercept` property.  That will capture all of the pre-encrypted/post-decrypted  data being sent back and forth.  Then you can troubleshoot what the server is complaining about.